# Use wshttpBinding with SSL and wsHttpBinding without SSL in single service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I want to use wshttpbinding (with SSL and without SSL) in single service but it not works, anybody had implemented it. So please guide how can i achieve that?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CommonBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="AzilenTechnology" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehaviour" name="wcfAllInOne.wcfFileIO">
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:82/WCFAllInOne/wcfFileIO.svc/basicHttpEndPoint" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" name="BasicHttp"
      contract="wcfAllInOne.IwcfFileIO" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:82/WCFAllInOne/wcfFileIO.svc/wsHttpBindingEndPoint" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" name="wsHttp" contract="wcfAllInOne.IwcfFileIO" />
    <endpoint address="https://localhost:444/WCFAllInOne/wcfFileIO.svc/wsHttpSslEndPoint" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" name="wsHttpSsl"
      contract="wcfAllInOne.IwcfFileIO" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Show us what configuration does not work for you.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution, why my last configuration doesn't work,

My first mistake is that i used same configuration for wsHttpBinding with ssl and wsHttpBinding Without SSL

Here in my config file,i had just created only one "**wsHttpBindingConfig**"  for both endpoint (one has http address and another one has https address),

Now i am using two different configuration for to solve this problem.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CommonBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="AzilenTechnologies" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security>
        <transport>
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpsBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="true"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None">
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security>
        <transport>
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CommonBehaviour" name="wcfAllInOne.wcfFileIO">
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="/basicHTTPEndPoint" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" name="basicHttp"
      contract="wcfAllInOne.IwcfFileIO" />
    <endpoint address="/wsHTTPEndPoint" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig"
      name="wsHttp" contract="wcfAllInOne.IwcfFileIO" />
    <endpoint address="/wsHTTPSEndPoint" binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="wsHttpsBindingConfig" name="wsHttpSsl"
      contract="wcfAllInOne.IwcfFileIO" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: <security mode="Transport"> is what enables https. Buy default mode is "None" and will be http only.